# Windows service installation returns error 1053

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services, nsis

I have created a Http Server(C++ Win 32 console application ) and I wanted to run it is service.
This server has main thread and Listener thread which will listen to the incoming traffic.main thread will block forever.

I have created a NSIS Installer which uses [SimpleSC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_Simple_Service_Plugin) plugin to install and the run the server

```
SimpleSC::InstallService "HttpServer" "HttpServer" "16" "2" "$INSTDIR\Server.exe" "" "" ""

SimpleSC::StartService "HttpServer" "" 30
```

I am able to install service but its not starting and return 1053 error.Is this because of main thread block ? Please help me on this.

Comment: Try using "net start HttpServer" from Command prompt (Admin mode if XP above).

Comment: @Abhineet I did that and I can see in service.msc it shows as starting and then goes off. "The service is not responding to the control function"

Comment: Then you have to look in the service creation code. How does it processes the passing of controls and what controls does it accepts.

Comment: Check the controls your service accepts by this:: "sc query HttpServer" - This cmd will show the details of your service. Under the "State", it shows the controls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in your service code. In the service control handler that you declared in the call to `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler()` you need to handle several request types and return according feedback to the system service manager. It let the system kow that your service is working correctly and what is its current state.

If you do not answer to all request types (esp. `SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE`), or if you do not answer in a limited time, the system will deduce that your service has failed / is stalled.

This is an example of control handler that I use in a code of mine:

```
//Feedback() is a custom function to put log into the system events and / or OutputDebugString()
//mSrvStatus is a global SERVICE_STATUS

void WINAPI SrvControlHandler(DWORD Opcode) {
    DWORD state;

    switch (Opcode) {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE:
            Feedback(FEED_EVENTS|FEED_ODS, "Pausing %s", SRVNAME);
            bActive = false;
            state = SERVICE_PAUSED;
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
            //refresh our settings from registry before continuing
            GetRegistrySettings();
            Feedback(FEED_EVENTS|FEED_ODS, "Continuing %s with refresh=%d", SRVNAME, dwRefresh);
            bActive = true;
            state = SERVICE_RUNNING;
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
            Feedback(FEED_EVENTS|FEED_ODS, "Stopping %s", SRVNAME);
            ReportSrvStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, NO_ERROR, 0); //ok, we begin to stop
            //The final ReportSrvStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0);
            //is sent from the function that started the service
            //that is waiting forever on the hSrvStopEvt event
            bActive = false;                                    //we tell the thread to stop fetching
            SetEvent(hSrvStopEvt);                              //and we signal the final event
            return;
            break;
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
            state = mSrvStatus.dwCurrentState;
            Feedback(FEED_ODS, "%s interrogated by SCM, returned %d", SRVNAME, state);
            break;
        default:
            Feedback(FEED_ODS, "other control resquest ?? - %d", Opcode);
            state = mSrvStatus.dwCurrentState;
    }
    ReportSrvStatus(state, NO_ERROR, 0);
}

/* Sets the current service status and reports it to the SCM.

 Parameters:
   dwCurrentState - The current state (see SERVICE_STATUS)
   dwWin32ExitCode - The system error code
   dwWaitHint - Estimated time for pending operation, in milliseconds
*/ 
void ReportSrvStatus( DWORD dwCurrentState,
                      DWORD dwWin32ExitCode,
                      DWORD dwWaitHint) {
    static DWORD dwCheckPoint = 1;

    mSrvStatus.dwCurrentState = dwCurrentState;
    mSrvStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = dwWin32ExitCode;
    mSrvStatus.dwWaitHint = dwWaitHint;

    if (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        mSrvStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0;
    else mSrvStatus.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP|SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE|SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;

    if ( (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING) ||
           (dwCurrentState == SERVICE_STOPPED) )
        mSrvStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    else mSrvStatus.dwCheckPoint = dwCheckPoint++;

    SetServiceStatus( hSrvStatus, &mSrvStatus );
}
```

Comment: Let me review my code.I will check what is missing in my code

Comment: @Chris_vr: feel free to ask any info. I cannot publish the whole code but I can post more info / excerpts if needed.